Invoke Sitecore service provider from SPE console
Is it possible to interact with Sitecore's DI container from the SPE command line? I was able to do this:
PS master:\>[Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::IsConfigured
True

But when I try to get a registered class, I get a strange error:
PS master:\>[Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::ServiceProvider::GetService([Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger])

 Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope] does not contain a method named 'GetService'.
 At line:1 char:1
 + [Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::ServiceProvider::GetSe ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

ServiceProviderEngineScope does have a GetService method, which makes me thing this error is due to some other syntax issue.

Ah, had a small syntax error. The second :: should have been a .:
 PS master:\>[Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::ServiceProvider.GetService([Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger])

 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[System.Object]

Get-Member shows I've indeed loaded the object:
PS master:\>[Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::ServiceProvider.GetService([Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger])| Get-Member
 
 
TypeName: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
 
Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
BeginScope  Method     System.IDisposable ILogger.BeginScope[TState](TState state)
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
IsEnabled   Method     bool ILogger.IsEnabled(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel)
Log         Method     void ILogger.Log[TState](Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId eventId, TState state, System.Exception exception, System.Func[...
ToString    Method     string ToString()

